# Components missing after migration from Joomla 1.5.22 to 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I performed a migration of my site in Joomla which was in version 1.5.22 to version 2.5 using jUpgrade. After the migration when I opened the url "mysite.com/jupgrade" to see how my new site will look, I am getting the error:

```
#404 Component not found
```

I checked into the jupgrade/components/ folder and noticed a number of components missing. The tables corresponding to the components are also missing. Do I need to migrate these components manually or some alternative solution is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some components will need to be done manually as a lot of them have 2 separate versions for 1.5 and 2.5. Simply install the Joomla 2.5 version of the extensions that aren't working and this should solve your problem

Comment: Actually these components were for custom functionality and were developed by some other developer. Do you have any idea on what step need to be followed to convert the 1.5 version component to 2.5 version?

Comment: depending on the complexity, it could take a very long time. Non-database module are easy where as ones that require database connections, article retrieving etc are harder. Take a look at 
[this](http://www.phoca.cz/documents/50-phoca/566-how-to-migrate-extensions-from-joomla-15-to-joomla-25) and [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847875/code-conversion-joomla-1-5-to-joomla-1-7-2-5)